# Error: Constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, subclass

```
public class A{

    public A(String x){
        System.out.println("A constructor Called "+x);
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        A a= new B("b");
     }
}

class B extends A{
    public B(String x){
        System.out.println("B constructor Called "+x);
    }
}
```

What is the problem in this very simple program, I am unable to locate it.
Getting the following error on compile:

```
A.java:13: error: constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;                                                                                                    
    public B(String x){                                                                                                                                                         
                      ^                                                                                                                                                         
  required: String                                                                                                                                                              
  found: no arguments                                                                                                                                                           
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since class A does not have a default constructor, you need to tell class B how to construct its parent:

```
class B extends A{
    public B(String x){
        super(x);  // this constructs the parent class
        System.out.println("B constructor Called "+x);
    }
}
```

The error is telling you that the constructor you must call requires a string:

> required: String

... however the one you are calling (which is the the default constructor because you are not calling `super` ) has no arguments:

> found: no arguments

Comment: And so if I remove the constructor for A, it will also remove this error. Which I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke the `super` constructor:

```
public B(String x){
    super(x);
    System.out.println("B constructor Called "+x);
}
```

Usually, there's an implicit call to a default no-arg constructor, but A doesn't have one of those. Writing `super(x);` will call the `public A(String x) ...` constructor, which is the only one available in the A class.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more.
If you will write no-argumnet constructor in hte parent class it will not show an error. Because by default super() call happens inside constructor. So when it's calling the parent class constructors it's not getting the no-argumnet constructor in the parent class.